# I am getting split error install when download the module

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

i used app bundle for dynamic download code when required while downloading code i am getting issue. Below is code

```
SplitInstallRequest request =
            SplitInstallRequest
                    .newBuilder()
                    // You can download multiple on demand modules per
                    // request by invoking the following method for each
                    // module you want to install.
                    .addModule("feature2")
                    .build();

    // Begin the installation of the feature1 module and handle success/failure
    splitInstallManager
            .startInstall(request)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {
                    // Module download successful
                    Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(getPackageName(), "com.bapspatil.feature2.FeatureTwoActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    // Module download failed; handle the error here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't download feature2: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: show the error.

Comment: @JohnJoe the error getting is com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallException: Split Install Error: -2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

There is now a [FakeSplitInstallManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/splitinstall/testing/package-summary.html) that can be used to simulate the installation of dynamic feature modules. It does require a code change (i.e. swapping the `SplitInstallManager` for the fake) for the time being, but it also allows you to also test scenarios such as network failure.

---

Today, the download of dynamic feature modules cannot be done from apps installed from Android Studio (or Gradle).

The download of dynamic feature modules can be tested in two ways:

- [Internal App Sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en): requires the app to be published in the store, but then you can upload bundles quickly (without changing the versionCode or even signing them) and you get a link you can open on the phone which installs the app.
- [Internal test track](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB): this method doesn't require a published app and serves the app immediately on the device of whitelisted accounts, but this is a release track so you need a signed App Bundle with a higher versionCode.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: No, thanks for asking. Now, you can use FakeSplitInstallManager. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Do you know if there are any tutorials for the `FakeSplitManager` and factory, they take a splits file location but I don't see any documentation on what that should be.

Comment: @casolorz check this - https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/test/testing-fakesplitinstallmanager#FakeSplitInstallManager